# Azure Websites Deployment Slot Routing with ChangeDecisionCallbackUrl

Tags: testing, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get dynamic routing working for Azure Websites. I can see the following article:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABTestingAndTestingInProductionWithAzureWebApps.aspx

This suggests using the "Testing in Production "TiP" callback functionality by setting the "ChangeDecisionCallbackUrl" property of the routing rule.

However, when I attempt to set this via PowerShell and then retrieve the value set, I cant see the url being set?

Therefore, I cant test the TiP extension is firing to do the dynamic routing I want.

Finding other instances where this is used is proving difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed **TiP Callback Extension** on your Azure web site.

[image]

Besides, if you use `-Debug` parameter with your powershell command `Set-AzureWebsite $siteName -Slot Production -RoutingRules $rule1 -Debug`, you could find details requests, and a request is sent to modify site/config.

[image]

From request body, you will find it contains routing rule that you specified, like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can comfirm that the extension is installed.

Comment: I can see the rules on the Http PUT of the config, but when I retrieve, the rules are not set up?

Answer (score 0):

I should add that when debugging setting the configuration, I see the following

```
  "RoutingRules": [
{
  "__type": "RampUpRule:http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure",
  "ActionHostName": "*********.azurewebsites.net",
  "ReroutePercentage": 10.0,
  "ChangeStep": 5.0,
  "ChangeIntervalInMinutes": 10,
  "MinReroutePercentage": 1.0,
  "MaxReroutePercentage": 80.0,
  "ChangeDecisionCallbackUrl": "https://*********.scm.azurewebsites.net/TipCallback/api/routing",
  "Name": "vNext"
}
```

but when I subsequently retrieve the configuration with Get-AzureWebsite -Debug, the routing configuration is "missing"?

```
  "RoutingRules": [
{
  "__type": "RampUpRule:http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure",
  "Name": "vNext",
  "ActionHostName": "********.azurewebsites.net",
  "ChangeDecisionCallbackUrl": **null**,
  "ChangeIntervalInMinutes": 10,
  "ChangeStep": 5,
  "MaxReroutePercentage": 80,
  "MinReroutePercentage": 1,
  "ReroutePercentage": 10
}
```

],

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on the GET call. ChangeDecisionCallbackUrl property is not populated. The fix will be out in next deployment, but in the meantime there is no reason why it wouldn't work.

If still there are issues, to eliminate PowerShell, I would like to ask you to use https://resources.azure.com as this is plain API